# Массивы Python. Сумма расстояний от первой точки до остальных точек

Tags: python

Условие: X и Y представляют координаты одной из n точек на плоскости. Найти
число точек, у которых ордината Y больше абсциссы X, и сумму расстояний
от первой точки до остальных точек. Ввод кол-ва точек и сами координаты идет с клавиатуры.

Не могу найти сумму расстояний от первой точки до остальных, помогите пж!

Вот код:

```
n = int(input('введите кол-во точек: '))

items = []
c = 0 # счетчик номеров точек
for i in range(n):
    c += 1
    x = int(input(f'введите x точки {c}: '))
    y = int(input(f'введите y точки {c}: '))

    items.append([x, y])

k = 0 # счетчик точек у которых Y больше чем X
for i in items:
    if i[1] > i[0]:
        k += 1

print(items)
print(k)
```

Comment: @passant да, я не смог это написать на питоне. теперь все понял, спасибо большое!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понял вопроса. `"Не могу найти сумму расстояний от первой точки до остальных",`  -  вы еще не учили на уроках геометрии формулу расстояния между двумя точками на плоскости? Или вы не знаете, как эту формулу запрограммировать на Python?

Если первое -  то подсказываю: корень квадратный из суммы квадратов покоординатных расстояний. А если второе, то например вот так:

```
import math    
for i in items[1:]:
    print(math.sqrt((items[0][0]-i[0])**2+(items[0][1]-i[1])**2))
```